# Use of dynamic bitset to convert decimal numbers

Tags: c++, bitset, boost-dynamic-bitset

I am solving a leetcode problem, which the output need to be a binary number without abundant digits.

I have the decimal number and I was trying to use bitset to do the conversion.

I wrote a function to return the number of digit given the number n:

```
int digitNum (int n){
    int digit = 0;
    while(n!=0){
        n/=2;
        digit++;
    }
    return digit;
}
```

But when I called it,

```
int digit = digitNum(res);
result = bitset<digit>(res).to_string();
```

the digit needs to be a constant. I read the boost::bitset, and I don't see how I can use a dynamic bitset to fix my problem. 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html

because it's defining each bit by hand. It doesn't convert to binary anymore.

Comment: If you have build errors, copy-paste those build errors (*as text*) into the body of the question instead. Then include e.g. comments in the code to show where the errors are.

Comment: As for your problem, templates are a pure compile-time feature of C++. Templates can't be created at run-time. Depending on your compiler you might want to research *constexpr*.

Comment: An image is worth a thousand words. An image of a word is worth a thousand words — in file size. Don't post images of code.

Answer (score 0):

bitset is a template. Any option in <> is generated at compile-time, so they can't take an input from a variable at runtime to choose template parameters. you can use a loop much like your existing one to do the same job as bitset:

```
string numToBits(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return "0";

    string temp;

    int n = (number > 0) ? number : - number;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        temp = string((n & 1) ? "1" : "0") + temp;
        n = n / 2;
    }

    if(number < 0) 
        temp = "-" + temp;

    return temp;
}
```